# Is $\Bbb Z^+ \times \Bbb Z^+$ countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question worded like so:

> Given $m, n \geq 1$, show that the set of $m * n$ matrices with elements within $\Bbb Z^+$ is countable

My assumption is half of the question doesn't matter and I should be focusing on $m, n \geq 1$. Since both $m$ and $n$ are in $\Bbb Z^+$, is it right to interpret this question as asking if $\Bbb Z^+ \times \Bbb Z^+$ is countable?

Comment: The Cartesian product of a finite collection of countable sets is countable.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown don't get ahead of yourself :P

Comment: you meant $\mathbb{Z}_+^{n \times m}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would interpret the question as asking whether $\prod_{i=1}^{mn}{\mathbb Z^+}$ is countable.  $\mathbb Z^+ \times \mathbb Z^+$ is just the set of all ordered **pairs** of positive integers.  You want an ordered **$mn$-tuple** of positive integers, one for each entry in the matrix.

Once you have this corrected interpretation of the question, then Lord Shark the Unknown's comment has the answer.

Comment: You're right. After actually typing out what I found objectionable about your answer, I realized that it doesn't really apply. If you make some minor edit to your answer, I will react my downvote as well. Until then, the system won't let me.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you.  I'm actually not concerned about the downvote, but I do want to make sure that I'm productively participating in the community by understanding positive and negative ways to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m,n>1$.

We will denote an $m \times n$ matrix with $(c_{ij}), i \in \{1,2...m\},j \in \{1,2,3...n\}$

Let the set $A$ be the set of $m \times n$ matrices.

Put:
 $$A_{1,1}= \bigcup_{c_{11} \in \Bbb{N}}\{(c_{ij})\}$$

$$A_{1,2}=\bigcup_{c_{12} \in \Bbb{N}} \{(c_{ij})\}$$ etc.

It is not difficult to prove that each $A_{ij}$ is countable when only the element $c_{ij}$ in the matrix, varies in the natural numbers.

So you can write $A=\bigcup_{i=1}^m \bigcup_{j=1}^n A_{ij}$ which is a finite union of countable sets,thus countable.